# How to sort items by multiple criteria in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list that's essentially [{location:1, mgr:'Joe', region:'Frank'}, {location:2, mgr:'Sam', region:'Jess'}, {location:3, mgr:'Joe', region:'Frank'}, {location:4, mgr:'Sue', region:'Frank'}, {location:5, mgr:'Susan', region:'Jess'}]. I need to get it into an order where the mgrs and regions are sorted by who has the lowest location number first but then grouped together. The mgrs and regions are names with no specific order except that their entries have to be together and the numbers correspond to specific locations, so they will never repeat,etc.

So the example should end up as:

"[{location:1, mgr:'Joe', region:'Frank'},{location:3, mgr:'Joe', region:'Frank'}, {location:4, mgr:'Sue', region:'Frank'}, {location:2, mgr:'Sam', region:'Jess'}, {location:5, mgr:'Susan', region:'Jess'}]"

Format doesn't really matter as I just need the locations in a correctly ordered list at the end. I haven't been able to find any similar examples and am struggling to figure out a way to approach this that isn't really convoluted (or even works).

I've tried a ton of different versions of this but my general thought was to iterate through and move entries to another list in the correct order. I've gotten close but there have still been entries not in the correct order. I also tried to sort with additional keys but kept running into issues with it sorting alphabetically or solely by the locations.

```
    correctlist = []
    originallist = [{location:1,mgr:'Joe',region:'Frank'},{location:2,mgr:'Sam',region:'Jess'},{location:3,mgr:'Joe',region:'Frank'},{location:4, mgr:'Sue', region:'Frank'},{location:5, mgr:'Susan', region:'Jess'}]

#Should end up as [{location:1,mgr:'Joe',region:'Frank'},{location:3,mgr:'Joe',region:'Frank'},{location:4, mgr:'Sue', region:'Frank'},{location:2,mgr:'Sam',region:'Jess'},{location:5, mgr:'Susan', region:'Jess'}]

    sortedlist = sorted(originallist, key=lambda k: (k['location']))

    while sortedlist:
        for location in sortedlist:
            currregion = location['region']
            currmgr = location['mgr']
            for locationin sortedlist:
                if location['region'] == currregion and location['mgr'] == currmgr:
                    correctlist.append(number)
                    sortedlist.remove(number)
            for location in sortedlist:
                if location['region'] == curregion:
                    currmgr = location['mgr']
            for locationin sortedlist:
                if location['mgr'] == currmgr and location['region'] == curregion:
                    correctlist.append(location)
                    sortedlist.remove(location)
```

Comment: So, region1 comes first because it has a 1, even though it also has a 3 and a 4 - and so averages out at 2.66, even if region 2 would average out at 2 if it only had a 2 (it has a 5, but what if)? You're grouping by region first and by manager per region, and you want the groups ordered by minimum value included in the group, and by value only - if there's two groups with the same minimum value, you don't care about the order? And within the group, everything is ordered by value only?

Comment: To clarify, the numbers/values will never repeat. They correspond to locations that are sorted numerically. There are gaps though, as not all locations are included. In my example, region2 would actually come first as it's minimum "location number" is lower than region1's minimum. Average is irrelevant as they are numeric identifiers and not values with any other significance. It's a strange system but unfortunately, I've been overruled on changing it.

Comment: Could you please actually provide `originallist`? In your text you say *"I have a list that's essentially {1,mgr1, region2}, {2, mgr3, region1}, {3, mgr1,region2}, {4, mgr5, region2}, {5, mgr2, region1}."* which is somewhat vague (what does "essentially" mean?). And then in your code you do `sortedlist = sorted(originallist, key=lambda k: (k['number']))` without defining `originallist`.

Comment: Presumably this can all be done, rather easily, with just `sorted` with an appropriate `key` argument; no need for all these `while` loops. However, it is extremely unclear to me by what logic you want to sort. You say *"So the example should end up as: {1,mgr1, region2}{3, mgr1,region2}{4, mgr5, region2}{2, mgr3, region1}{5, mgr2, region1}"* and I have no idea by which logic you arrived at this result.

Comment: @Stef I added keys and dummy info to the example to clarify. I definitely see how giving them numbered titles instead of names is confusing. The location number is the starting point, so the lowest one is first, then all of the entries with the same mgr then the same region (still grouping by mgr and in numerical order within each "group"). Then when that mgr/region is exhausted, the lowest location number goes next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and simple way to group elements together in python is usually to use a dict of lists.

When we have grouped everything nicely in sublists of regions and subsublists of managers, we can sort each subsublist and then each sublist.

If each manager's subsublist is sorted by location, then the lowest location is going to be in its first element, so we can sort the sublist of manager's subsublists by looking at the location of the first element of each manager's subsublist.

Then we can chain the manager's subsublists together into a sorted sublist representing the region.

Then each region sublist is sorted, so its lowest location is going to be in its first element, so we can sort the list of region sublists by looking at the location of the first element of each region sublist.

Then we can chain all the sublists together into a sorted list.

```py
from itertools import chain

originallist = [{'location':1,'mgr':'Joe','region':'France'},{'location':2,'mgr':'Sam','region':'Japan'},{'location':3,'mgr':'Joe','region':'France'},{'location':4, 'mgr':'Sue', 'region':'France'},{'location':5, 'mgr':'Susan', 'region':'Japan'}]
# I replaced 'Franck' with 'France' and 'Jessica' with 'Japan' to avoid confusiong between regions and managers

def grouped_by_region(originallist):
    regions = {}
    for lmr in originallist:
        regions.setdefault(lmr['region'], []).append(lmr)
    return regions

# print(grouped_by_region(originallist))
## {'France': [{'location': 1, 'mgr': 'Joe', 'region': 'France'}, {'location': 3, 'mgr': 'Joe', 'region': 'France'}, {'location': 4, 'mgr': 'Sue', 'region': 'France'}],
##  'Japan': [{'location': 2, 'mgr': 'Sam', 'region': 'Japan'}, {'location': 5, 'mgr': 'Susan', 'region': 'Japan'}]}

def grouped_by_mgr(region):
    by_mgr = {}
    for lmr in region:
        by_mgr.setdefault(lmr['mgr'], []).append(lmr)
    return by_mgr

# regions = grouped_by_region(originallist)
# print(grouped_by_mgr(regions['France']))
## {'Joe': [{'location': 1, 'mgr': 'Joe', 'region': 'France'}, {'location': 3, 'mgr': 'Joe', 'region': 'France'}], 'Sue': [{'location': 4, 'mgr': 'Sue', 'region': 'France'}]}

## PUTTING IT ALL TOGETHER
def sorted_by_region_mgr_location(originallist):
    regions = grouped_by_region(originallist)
    for region_name, region in regions.items():
        #print('\nregion: ', region_name)
        by_mgr = grouped_by_mgr(region)
        #print('grouped by mgr: ', by_mgr)
        for group in by_mgr.values():
            group.sort(key=lambda lmr: lmr['location'])  # sort within each manager group
        sorted_groups = sorted(by_mgr.values(), key=lambda group: group[0]['location'])  # sort managers within each region
        #print('sorted groups: ', sorted_groups)
        regions[region_name] = list(chain.from_iterable(sorted_groups))
        #print('final list: ', regions[region_name])
    #print('\n\nregions before chaining: ', regions)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(sorted(regions.values(), key=lambda region: region[0]['location'])))

print(
    sorted_by_region_mgr_location(originallist)
)
```

Result:

```
[{'location': 1, 'mgr': 'Joe', 'region': 'France'}, {'location': 3, 'mgr': 'Joe', 'region': 'France'}, {'location': 4, 'mgr': 'Sue', 'region': 'France'}, {'location': 2, 'mgr': 'Sam', 'region': 'Japan'}, {'location': 5, 'mgr': 'Susan', 'region': 'Japan'}]
```